# Modeling swarm behaviour in python

Tags: python, tkinter, visualization, particles

I am looking for a graphic solution (a library) to visualise swarm behaviour with python.
The whole set will be an ant-like swarm of particles/objects moving across 2D space, bumping, leaving trace, and following trace, and interacting in various ways.
I could do all the computation in the background but still I would like to visualise it somehow.

And here comes the tricky part:
When there is more than several thousand particles moving, the computation takes so much resources there is not enough power to do whimsical stuff like visualisation of trail with additional sprites or tkinter_polygons, as this creates too many objects to run the visualisation smoothly. (I have tried tkinter for this).

On the other hand all the graphic - particles, and the trail, and the other conditions of the environment could be calculated and generated as a single image - a numpy.array (which would be reasonably fast, as I understand) but I know not of any suitable library able to show/visualise the arrays with reasonable frame frequency. Like rendering frames of a movie.

I tend towards arrays solution as this would give me data feedback [at any point of time the code would contain information of the whole environment state regardless of visualisation/GUI] as I need this for particle interactions. Although I know that moving polygons across canvas and reading the current state from GUI [eg. collisions] is probbably easier to code.

Where should I start?
pygame?
tkinter?
PyQT?
Dash?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
Your post is far too broad to be a Stack Overflow question, and you're asking for tutorial guidance -- off-topic here.

Comment: pygame or ursina engine seem better for this than tkinter imo, also for pure mathematical calculations You can use numba library to speed up those processes

Comment: If you have *more than several thousand particles moving*, I advise you to look at C++ or another compiled language. To run it smoothly you will need to have a lot of optimisations which you can't really get from python.

Answer (score 2):

You can check [OpenCV](https://opencv.org).

Here's an example with 1,000 particles with random starting coordinates and velocities:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# generate particle coordinates, velocities
n = 1000
cs = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (2, n))
vs = np.random.uniform(-0.01, 0.01, (2, n))

# set image size
s = 200

cv2.namedWindow('img')
while True:
    # calculate new coordinates
    cs += vs
    
    # generate image from coordinates
    img = np.zeros((s, s, 3))
    img[tuple((cs * s % s).astype(int))] = 1

    # show frame and wait 40ms
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    cv2.waitKey(40)
```

Output:

[image: animation]

Comment: Great answer but out of curiosity: Why didn't you use `PIL` with `tkinter` (would be more customisable)? How would you do about a problem where all of the particles can interact with each other? Would you still use numpy?

Comment: TBH no reason other than that I'm personally more familiar with OpenCV, and it seems to do the job here... maybe it's my hammer and somehow the question looks like a nail :)

Comment: Regarding the case of interacting particles, I think it's highly problem-specific. For simple things numpy should be OK. If you want something more efficient, but still want to use python, numba could be an interesting direction to look at (also, I haven't done it, but apparently it is possible with numba to offload the calculations to a GPU, which can be very significant for efficiency)

Comment: Well I would have went with tensorflow :D. One last question: Why did you normalise `cs` (between 0 and 1) instead of leaving it between 0 and 200?

Comment: I just thought it would be nice to have the actual simulation in the (0, 1) coordinate space, and have a separate visualisation parameter `s` that I can tweak to find the size of the window that works well

Comment: Also wouldn't it be faster if you do `cs %= 1` just after the `cs += vs` instead of calling `% s` on each one separately?

Comment: @TheLizzard Yes, so of course you want to avoid loops in python wherever you can if efficiency matters. For that simple visualisation it wasn't a problem, but I updated the code to make it all vectorized. See the updated answer, it is now about 80x faster than the original version